# combobox return System.Data.DataRowView when dataset return value is null

Tags: c#, combobox

Try to bind combobox but returning System.Data.DataRowView when ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count >0 but the return value is null.

```
cbox.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
cbox.DisplayMember = displayValue;
cbox.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: I tried and your code seems to work fine. Have you tried not setting the selected index to -1? You can also try setting the ValueMember to the unique identifier column.

Answer (score 0):

It's work's for me, you can try it's help for u

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Default");
            dt.Columns.Add("DatabaseName");
            dt.Rows.Add("Sample");
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "DatabaseName";
            comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("Default1");
            dt1.Columns.Add("DatabaseName");
            ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
            comboBox2.DisplayMember = "DatabaseName";
            comboBox2.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
```